# Cocos2d-x RemoveFromParentAndCleanUp(false) does not work

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, action, removechild

I'm trying to change the parent of the node like this:

```
Vec2 position = _newParent->convertToNodeSpace(_node->convertToWorldSpace(Point(0,0)));
//_node->getParent()->removeChild(_node, false);
_node->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false);
_newParent->addChild(_node);
_node->setPosition(position);
_node->resume();
```

But despite "false" in the cleanup parameter, _node doesn't continue any actions added to it earlier.
Is this a bug or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and it was my fault. Before changing the parent, I have removed the parent from it's own parent with cleanup, so the second "cleanup" in the code above does not matter.